# Grep different kinds of patterns

Tags: awk, grep, wildcards, pattern-matching

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>sp|P43238|ALL12_ARAHY Allergen Ara h 1, clone P41B OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|N1NG13|N1NG13_ARAHY Seed storage protein Ara h1 OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|Q6PSU6|Q6PSU6_ARAHY Conarachin (Fragment) OS=Arachi  (303 aa)
29.4% identity
>>tr|Q6PSU3|Q6PSU3_ARAHY Conarachin (Fragment) OS=Arachi  (580 aa)
29.4% identity
>>tr|A5Z1Q5|A5Z1Q5_ARADU Ara d 6 OS=Arachis duranensis O  (145 aa)
23.7% identity
>>sp|P43237|ALL11_ARAHY Allergen Ara h 1, clone P17 OS=A  (614 aa)
29.4% identity
>>tr|A8VT50|A8VT50_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A1YQB2|A1YQB2_BOVIN Alpha lactabumin (Fragment) OS=  (52 aa)
50.0% identity
>>tr|A5Z1Q8|A5Z1Q8_ARADU Ara d 2.01 OS=Arachis duranensi  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT44|A8VT44_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT41|A8VT41_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|N1NEW2|N1NEW2_ARADU Seed storage protein Ara h1 OS=  (614 aa)
29.4% identity
>>tr|B3IXL2|B3IXL2_ARAHY Main allergen Ara h1 OS=Arachis  (614 aa)
29.4% identity
>>tr|A8VT50|A8VT50_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
2>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>sp|P43238|ALL12_ARAHY Allergen Ara h 1, clone P41B OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
```

I want to retrieve the lines above those where the identity is greater than or equal to 35%. The expected output is this:

```
1>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>sp|P43238|ALL12_ARAHY Allergen Ara h 1, clone P41B OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|N1NG13|N1NG13_ARAHY Seed storage protein Ara h1 OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|A8VT50|A8VT50_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A1YQB2|A1YQB2_BOVIN Alpha lactabumin (Fragment) OS=  (52 aa)
50.0% identity
>>tr|A5Z1Q8|A5Z1Q8_ARADU Ara d 2.01 OS=Arachis duranensi  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT44|A8VT44_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT41|A8VT41_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity  2>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>sp|P43238|ALL12_ARAHY Allergen Ara h 1, clone P41B OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
```

I tried the following: but haven't had any luck yet:

```
grep -B1 "35\+.*" -e '>>>' file > output_file
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are they actually a single line?  In your input it seems like it's anywhere from 2-3 lines, somewhat arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. They are all separate lines. I want to keep the "PROKKA" line, along with any line that is equal to or greater than 35.0%, and the line immediately above it, i.e the lines starting with '>>'

Comment: Is the embedded string "2>>>PROKKA ..." supposed to be a separate line?

Comment: Yes.. we have 10000+ lines with PROKKA, each starting as 1>>>, 2>>>, 3>>> etc..

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid trying to do numeric comparisons using regular expressions. As well, since `-B` is a global option you will inevitably get the line before the `>>>` pattern too.

You could do something like this in awk instead:

```
$ awk '/>>>/ {print} />>tr/ {last = $0} $1+0 >= 35 {print last; print}' file
1>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|N1NG13|N1NG13_ARAHY Seed storage protein Ara h1 OS=  (626 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|A8VT50|A8VT50_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A1YQB2|A1YQB2_BOVIN Alpha lactabumin (Fragment) OS=  (52 aa)
50.0% identity
>>tr|A5Z1Q8|A5Z1Q8_ARADU Ara d 2.01 OS=Arachis duranensi  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT44|A8VT44_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
>>tr|A8VT41|A8VT41_ARADU Conglutin OS=Arachis duranensis  (160 aa)
44.8% identity
2>>>PROKKA_00001 Transcriptional regulator PadR-like family protein - 137 aa
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
>>tr|E5G076|E5G076_ARAHY Ara h 1 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (619 aa)
37.3% identity
```

The `$1 + 0` conversion of the percentage strings seems to be supported at least by `gawk` and `mawk`.

Comment: There is one minor problem though in the output. The 'PROKKA' line is being printed thrice, for every one of them apart from the first. Is there a way to get rid of that?

example from output:
`>>tr|Q9AXI0|Q9AXI0_ARAHY Oleosin variant B OS=Arachis hy  (176 aa)`
`46.2% identity`
`84344>>>PROKKA_85463 hypothetical protein - 46 aa`
`84344>>>PROKKA_85463 hypothetical protein - 46 aa`
`84344>>>PROKKA_85463 hypothetical protein - 46 aa`
`>>tr|B4XID4|B4XID4_ARAHY Ara h 7 allergen OS=Arachis hyp  (164 aa)`
`50.0% identity`